# Do you want to blog about becoming fit and working out?

Tags: discussion, top-7, blog

### We're actively looking for users who want to write blog posts!

I'm looking for help from users who want to help breath life into a Fitness.SE blog! On Super User [we got officially blessed by Jeff](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2153/1548) and I honestly believe that Gaming should be able to deserve one as well.

On Super User we mainly started out with [Questions of the Week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2249/super-user-questions-of-the-week-9), which help create a steady stream of content, because every week there's at least one notable question. or the rest we mainly focused on putting our users content in the spotlight, though Fitness.SE has the advantage that it has a topic that most of our users love doing: exercise! While some might think a QotW post would just be a matter of copy pasting, on the site we have to be on-topic and mainly focus on answering the question. Blog posts however, have a measure of artistic liberty, so you can add more context and interesting information.

We could for example blog about:

- your **personal progress** in some training program, working towards a goal,
- some **awesome achievement** or great result at a race, with pretty photo finishes and all!
- your **favorite exercise gadget** or machine (heart rate monitor or kettle bell),
- some **basic  explanations** about nutrition or exercise physiology for the uninitiated,
- **interviews** with special or interesting users.

Off course, we're a small community as of yet and we don't get a ton of questions. But nearly everyone has interesting experiences to share! Lost 30 pounds? Your story on how you got there may inspire others to follow your example!

[**So how does this work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs)

If you're interested please show your interest by posting an answer. Please also share your ideas about what we should be blogging about or how we should organize it.

Comment: We now have a set a guidelines for Stack Exchange Community blogs, so make sure you check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509.

Comment: I absolutely intend to put up some content as I find the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [We now officially have our own blog!](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/)

But we need more writers. Currently signed up are:

- Nathan Wheeler
- Barbie
- Evan Plaice
- Greg
- YYY
- VPeric
- Eimantas

So anyone who's interested in writing an occasional blog post, just drop into our chatroom!

Comment: IS this blog still maintained? I'd be interested in contributing.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  While tempting, the one thing I know is that I can't keep up with blogging.  At most, I would be able to put a quality post a month.  I'm pretty sure no-one wants to see current measurements, tracking, etc.  That's more germain to Twitter anyway.

There's always gym frustrations (20 guys fighting for the same bench and people taking 40 minutes to push the bar 5 times).  But more useful would be the qualitative side of things.  Diet/fitness programs that you are looking in to, rationale for choosing one over the other.  Reactions to hyperbole prevalent all over weight lifting sites, etc.

I'd consider it if I'm *not* the only guy posting something.

Comment: Well you surely won't be the only. Though it will take some time to convince more users to participate off course. Either way, on Super User a lot of posts are just a way to summarize all the answers in one big post, which means you don't always need to find all the information yourself, just digest them in a sensible way. Furthermore, your answers are already short blog posts and if you find your repeating certain portions of the answers, you could consider explaining them in a blog post so we can point to that in the future :-)

Comment: I tried setting up an account for you, but something seems to have gone wrong. However, if you have any ideas on what you'd want to write about, just post them here or simply mail me a draft and I'll upload it for you

Comment: Hi @Berin, I'm going on a vacation for three weeks and was hoping if you could try and write a blog post next week or the week after that.

Comment: Hmm.  Just got back from vacation.  I'll have to get situated there then.

Comment: Can't figure out how to log in...  I don't see a button or link or anything.

Comment: Http://Fitness.blogoverflow.com/wp-login

Comment: I get a "Oh no, 404" page when I follow that link.  Perhaps I don't have an account set up or something?

Answer (score 2):

Much like Berin, I like the concept a lot but I worry about my ability to stay consistent with my posts.  Which, really, just makes the BlogOverflow format even more attractive to me.  I won't feel morbidly guilty if I can't make a post for two weeks due to a busy schedule.

So sure, I will pass along my entry in the next few days, assuming life does not throw more crucial things my way. :)

Comment: Great to hear that @YYY, the way we have it set up at Super User right now is that we have 5 editors, who are each in charge of one day. They don't necessarily have to write themselves each week, just make sure something get's posted in his/her theme. That way, if we can get several users to contribute, you only need to write 1 post every two weeks.

Comment: Besides, the focus is on highlighting content from the site, adding context to a question and answer or give some additional/deeper explanations. Or for instance a diary about your own 'journey' to some sports event, doesn't have to be a whole essay, but rather a digest of how you tackle common problems. So I'm quite positive we can make this work out.

Answer (score 2):

I would be interested in blogging some when I find the time. I would write on weight-loss and running. I'm not sure how much time that I can devote to it, but I'll be happy to help out where I can!

Answer (score 2):

I just posted this idea [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1892105#1892105) - but what do you guys think about writing guest posts for other blogs? I noticed that [JCDFitness](http://jcdfitness.com/contact/) is accepting guest posts right now, and his blog is pretty big. I think if we could put together something that showcases fitness.stackexchange.com it would be a really great promotion opportunity (we can include links and stuff!). What do you guys think? Anybody want to give it a shot?

PS - I'm not sure how much longer this will be happening (just discovered it today), so let's talk about it fast! It's also a good thing to keep in mind if other big fitness bloggers do guest posts in the future.