# Fitness 101 - Seeking a writer for "finding the right exercise for you"

Tags: discussion, blog

If you haven't been reading the blog, we are starting a [Fitness 101 series](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/keeping-your-new-years-resolution-with-fitness-101/) to kick off 2012 and offer information and tips for people looking to fulfill their New Year's fitness resolutions.

To get the momentum going, we will need volunteers to help create content and write on different topics. Lauren, Ivo, and I have outlined some ideas already in [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yHbcQGFOCp1YGtG66nM-u5wlBXWOmAjwKg_2QlismBo/edit). Our next topic on hand is **finding the right exercise for you**. Some of the important questions to address are:

- What kind of exercise should I do?
- How do I find the right trainer/outlet/gym for my routine?
- I am overweight. Where should I start?
- How often should I exercise?
- What medical conditions or history do I need take into consideration?

There are other topics that are worthy of their own blog posts so please have a look through and feel free to edit the document. As time goes on, we will begin to address other topics such as nutrition, running, weightlifting, and whatever else springs up from suggestions and feedback from our users and blog readers.

If you are interested, drop a note in chat or leave an answer if you would like to write a post for the blog. At the moment, we are specifically looking for someone to take on the next topic outlined here. Even if you don't contribute to the Fitness 101 series, you are still allowed to blog about [becoming fit and working out](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/do-you-want-to-blog-about-becoming-fit-and-working-out).

**EDIT:** I had begun to tackle this topic since no one else has stepped forward yet, but ended up writing a blog post about [defining your fitness goals](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/defining-your-fitness-goals/) to keep the subject matter more focused, but we still would like someone to help out and write a post about **finding the right exercise for you and your goals**.

Comment: Anyone...? Bueller... Bueller...