# Next Fitness 101 Blog Topic - Intro to Nutrition

Tags: discussion, blog

One of the next topics in the [Fitness 101 blog series](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/keeping-your-new-years-resolution-with-fitness-101/) is doing a "nutrition 101" type post. Instead of enumerating things of "don't eat X (because it's bad), eat Y (because it's good)" which will just cause people to do "Duh, I already knew that," the post should focus on taking some **actionable steps** in order to achieve better nutrition.

Since nutrition encompasses a breadth of items, starting out with single, narrower topics would be better than trying to capture a broad overview in one topic. Here are some ideas for nutrition:

- protein
- fats
- sugar
- carbohydrates

If you are interested in writing about one of these topics, **please volunteer and state your interest** (and also write it too...) to help push this further along. Feel free to suggest other topics too and contribute to the [Google Docs document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yHbcQGFOCp1YGtG66nM-u5wlBXWOmAjwKg_2QlismBo/edit?hl=en_US) created by Ivo.

Note: ["Finding the Right Exercise For You"](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/fitness-101-seeking-a-writer-for-finding-the-right-exercise-for-you) still needs a volunteer to help write the post.